# При попытке создать любую базу, вылазит данная ошибка

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, intellij-idea, h2

[image: ошибка такая]

пытаюсь создать таблицу для использования jdbc + h2, но не как не могу понять как создать ее [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Особенности работы с H2

Одной из особенностей H2 - является работа в режиме `in-memory`.

Данный режим практически ничего не требует указывать в свойствах подключения и крайне прост в настройке и по этой причине он чаще всего используется при запуске новичками(*и далеко не всегда это делается осознанно*).

При запуске H2 в `in-memory` режиме база данных хранится в оперативной памяти.
И как следует из вышесказанного весь жизненный цикл жизни данной БД, как правило, умещается в один запуск (если не указано обратного). Т.е. база данных создается при запуске приложения и удаляется целиком и полностью по его завершению.
Отсюда следует, что создавать и инициализировать все таблицы приложение должно самостоятельно при каждом запуске.

Как правило это используется при автоматизированном тестировании, когда вам нужно многократно восстанавливать одно и тоже состояние БД.

Поэтому вообще не факт, что та база данных которую вы видите в консоле IDE и та база данных, которую видит ваше Java-приложение - это одно и тоже.
Поэтому в данном случае создавать в консоле таблицы и ждать, что их увидит ваше Java-приложение бессмысленно.

**Другие режимы работы H2**

Стоит отметить что `in-memory` не является единственным режимом работы с БД H2.
В Вашем случае для простоты можно попробовать воспользоваться `embedded`-режимом, при котором данные хранятся не в оперативной памяти, а в файле.

Для корректной работы данной базы данных архиважно правильно указать подключение:

**на диске в домашней папке:**

```
jdbc:h2:~/dbname
```

**на диске в указанном каталоге**

```
jdbc:h2:./path/to/database
```

или

```
jdbc:h2:file:/path/to/database
```

**в памяти**

```
jdbc:h2:mem:dbname
```

> **Важно:**
> В IDE укажите ту же строку подключения, что и в Java-коде.
> Желательно ссылаться на конкретный файл, к которому будет доступ и IDE и у приложения.

### Ошибка при добавлении внешнего ключа

Ошибка происходит в момент выполнения следующего выражения:

```sql
alter table Ingredient_Ref
    add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id);
```

**В ошибке сказано:**

> **[90057][90057]**
> Ограничение "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" не найдено 
> Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" not found

В ней **H2** явно ругается на отсутствие ограничений(`unique` или `primary key`) в поле  `id` (таблица `Ingredient`)

Другими словами: поле `Ingredient_Ref.ingredient` не может ссылаться на `Ingredient` и являться внешним ключом, поскольку поле `id` таблицы `Ingredient` **НЕ ГАРАНТИРУЕТ** нахождение одной единственной строки, которую можно ассоциировать с указанным значением. т.е. в вашем случае в эту таблицу возможно вставить несколько строк со значением `id=1` и `H2` не сможет понять, какую именно строку вы имели в виду.

Для исправления данного недоразумения, следует для таблицы `Ingredient` указать первичный ключ.

```
ALTER TABLE Ingredient ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

Перед тем как вы попытаетесь сделать это:

```sql
alter table Ingredient_Ref
    add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id);
```

Comment: Спасибо Михаилу за подробное объяснение данного материала, исправил sql запрос, все заработало, но с h2 проблемы были до тех пор, пока я вручную в intelijIdea - schema не создал таблицу и уже туда положил свой sql запрос